# Service POWER_CONNECTED& POWER_DISCONNECTED. Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, service, background

I had an app with one service running in the background which collects data. It is possible to start this service while plug the USB charger and stop it when unplug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just register receiver for both actions:

```
registerReceiver(yourReceiver, IntentFilter().apply{
    addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)
    addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)
}
```

And in your onReceive:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    when (intent.action) {
        Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED -> {
            startService(Intent(context, ServiceClassName::class.java))
        }
        Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED -> {
            stopService(Intent(context, ServiceClassName::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```